# SQL Query to take a datetime past midnight and remove a day from it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a stored procedure involving employee hours worked. I have a database consisting of employee logs consisting of something similar to what follows:

```
Emp ID   Event             Time
xxxxx    Log In            9/1/2016 8:00 PM
xxxxx    Start Driving     9/1/2016 8:15 PM
xxxxx    Load              9/1/2016 10:30 PM
xxxxx    Driving           9/1/2016 11:00 PM
xxxxx    Unload            9/2/2016 1:00 AM
xxxxx    Driving           9/2/2016 1:30 AM
xxxxx    Log Out           9/2/2016 4:00 AM
```

What I am trying to do is insert this data into another table with a Shift Date column that would check for the time past midnight and assign it a value of the previous day so that the whole shift would have 1 shift date.

This is the stored procedure I am trying to use to pull the date

```
Convert(date,
     IIf(dr.[Terminal Name] Like '*PM Drivers*',
     --true condition statement for first IIF
     IIF(datepart(hour,
     --datepart value
     IIF(pn.effective_dt_local IS NOT NULL, pn.effective_dt_local,
     IIF(pn.settings<>'',DateAdd(hour,5,pn.effective_datetime),pn.effective_datetime)))<10,
    --true condition for second 
     IIF dateadd(day,-1,IIF(pn.effective_dt_local IS NOT NULL, pn.effective_dt_local,
     IIF(pn.settings<>'',DateAdd(hour,-5,pn.effective_datetime),pn.effective_datetime))),
   --false condition for second IIF
     IIF(pn.effective_dt_local IS NOT NULL, pn.effective_dt_local,
     IIF(pn.settings<>'',DateAdd(hour,-5,pn.effective_datetime),pn.effective_datetime))),
    --false condition for second IIF
     IIF(pn.effective_dt_local IS NOT NULL, pn.effective_dt_local, 
     IIF(pn.settings<>'',DateAdd(hour,-5,pn.effective_datetime),pn.effective_datetime))))
```

The problem I am getting is that the date is never being adjusted for a time after midnight. I am fairly certain it is something simple I am missing but can't seem to figure it out.  I was able to get a similar query working in access using the same logic however Access has the datevalue function that sqlserver does not.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated at this point.  Thank you

Comment: "...Time past midnight and assign it the previous day." So you would need to have a known date in which you are comparing other dates to?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just store the start datetime and the number of minutes?

Comment: or a  shift start date.

Comment: Why would you use `IIF()` instead of `CASE`, the SQL standard expression for this purpose?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out is the shift start date.  So essentially any time that is worked before 6 am would have a shift start date of the previous day for a driver with a terminal name like '*pm drivers'

Comment: Used `IIF()` as it is what I used in the original access query and I am generally more familiar with it than `CASE`

Comment: That would work as long as employees are prevented from working past shift end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was being an idiot and using the wrong wildcard characters in my like statement. Should have been using `%` instead of `*` So that initial like statement should be 
     `Like '%PM Drivers%'` not `Like '*PM Drivers*',`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to match the log in and log out

```
declare @temp table (Emp_id int, [Event] varchar(50), Time datetime);

insert into @temp values (1, 'Log In', '9/1/2016 8:00pm')
insert into @temp values (1, 'Log Out', '9/2/2016 4:00AM')


insert into @temp values (1, 'Log In', '9/2/2016 8:00pm')
insert into @temp values (1, 'Log Out', '9/3/2016 4:00AM')


;with logs as
(
    select
        Emp_ID,
        [Event],
        [Time],
        row_number() over (Partition by Emp_ID order by Emp_ID) as Ord
    from @temp
    where [Event] in ('Log In', 'Log Out')
)

select 
    li.Emp_ID,
    li.[Time],
    datediff(mi, li.time, lo.time) / 60.0
from
(
    select 
        *
    from logs
    where Event = 'Log In'
) li
    inner join
    (
        select 
            *
        from logs
        where Event = 'Log Out'
    ) lo
        on li.Emp_id = lo.Emp_id
            and lo.ord = li.ord + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and this would normally work however drivers may log out multiple times during a shift for breaks or switching delivery vehicles etc.. I should have used a more detailed example in my original post.

Comment: @Tom yeah, that's a different use case.  you might update your question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Can you take 6 hours from the date and convert it to a date, any time up to 6 am will go to the previous day any time after that would stay on the same day.

```
select [ShiftStartDate] = convert(date,dateadd(hour, -6,pn.effective_dt_local))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was a way to do it prior to 2008 R2. With the inclusion of the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` windowing functions the solution could be reduced to 1/3 the size.

```
SELECT 
    Activity.EmployeeID,
    SHIFTS.ThisShiftLogin,
    Activity.EventName,
    Activity.EventTime
FROM
    @T Activity
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ShiftStart.EmployeeID,
            ThisShiftLogin=ShiftStart.LoginDate,
            NextShiftLogin=NextShiftStart.LoginDate
         FROM
         (
             SELECT 
                EmployeeID,
                LoginDate=MIN(EventTime),
                RowID=ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY MIN(EventTime))
             FROM 
                @T 
            WHERE 
                EventName='Log In'
            GROUP BY 
                EmployeeID,
                DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, EventTime))
         )AS ShiftStart
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (
            SELECT 
                EmployeeID,
                LoginDate=MIN(EventTime),
                RowID=ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY MIN(EventTime))
             FROM 
                @T 
            WHERE 
                EventName='Log In'
            GROUP BY 
                EmployeeID,
                DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, EventTime))
         )AS NextShiftStart ON ShiftStart.RowID=NextShiftStart.RowID-1
    )AS SHIFTS ON 
        Activity.EmployeeID=SHIFTS.EmployeeID 
        AND
        (
            (SHIFTS.NextShiftLogin IS  NULL AND Activity.EventTime >= SHIFTS.ThisShiftLogin)
            OR 
            (NOT SHIFTS.NextShiftLogin IS  NULL AND Activity.EventTime >= SHIFTS.ThisShiftLogin AND Activity.EventTime < SHIFTS.NextShiftLogin )
        )
```